# How to emit debug information using llvm ir in Clang?

Tags: c, clang, llvm, clang++, llvm-ir

Using clang or clang++ the command of
 `clang -S -emit-llvm ./source.c`
will create a llvm ir document. However debugging information is missing. So when you test and compile things you lose debugging information.

How does one can make clang emit human readable llvm ir document with debug information ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard option to add debug info is `-g`. So, running `clang -g -S -emit-llvm source.c` will emit necessary information